# AudioKit, create eq from reference file

Tags: audiokit, simulate, equalizer

I'm working with an audio app and Im using the amazing AudioKit.
Now, I want to color my app sounds with the eq-curve of an old speaker cabinet. I have this reference audio file which contains white noise that was played back through this speaker cabinet and then recorded with a mic. 
I´ve manually analyzed the file in a music DAW and created a parametric eq with 60 AKEqualizerFilter, but it must be a better way..?! Both time wise and performance wise.. Ive also tried the AKConvolution by sending it a very short clip of the filtered white noise, but its most hearable on the very short slap back it produces..

Any tips would be great! Thanks